# material-ui 0.15.2 renders additional vendor-prefixed styles on the server but not the client, leading to React 15.2.1 warnings

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, isomorphic-javascript, vendor-prefix

I am using the following setup:

- `react` version `15.2.1`
- `material-ui` version `0.15.2`
- `express` and `universal-router` for server-side rendering

Where ever I use a `material-ui` component I get the following kind of error:

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:

 (client) uot;);mui-prepared:;" data-reactid="36">
 (server) uot;);mui-prepared:;-webkit-transition:a
```

The reason for this error is because there is a discrepancy between the HTML rendered by `express` and that rendered by my browser (and the issue is not browser-specific; I've tried on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, all with the same result).

Here is the server-generated HTML for one component (`Paper`).

```
<div class="Cv_me_2f3" style="color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);background-color:#ffffff;transition:all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);box-shadow:0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16),
         0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);border-radius:50%;background-image:url(&quot;https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANxAAAAJGU3NGRhZmNiLWExZjMtNGY3MC1hNzNjLWY4OTJlMGJmZTcyYQ.jpg&quot;);mui-prepared:;-webkit-transition:all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;" data-reactid="36">
```

Here is the client HTML for the same component.

```
<div class="Cv_me_2f3" style="color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);background-color:#ffffff;transition:all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);box-shadow:0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16),
         0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);border-radius:50%;background-image:url(&quot;https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANxAAAAJGU3NGRhZmNiLWExZjMtNGY3MC1hNzNjLWY4OTJlMGJmZTcyYQ.jpg&quot;);mui-prepared:;" data-reactid="36"></div>
```

Here is the difference (and it is consistently this same kind of difference regardless of component).

In the `style` attribute towards the very end...

```
style="...mui-prepared:;-webkit-transition:all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;" data-reactid="36"
```

If it isn't clear the `-webkit-transition` and `-moz-box-sizing` attributes were added somehow on the server only.

I looked into and found that `material-ui`'s theming system using some prefixer to automatically prefix any inline styles it uses, I believe with `inline-style-prefixer`. However, I am not sure how to use this information.

I know `inline-style-prefixer` has a `static` version that could be used so that the client and server are forced to have the same `userAgent` in effect. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

pass user-agent value contained in http request headers can fix this problem

```
global.navigator.userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'] || 'all';
```